# wcf client configuration

Tags: wcf, configuration, client, app-config

I have wcf client. It uses .NET 3.5. 
When I compile the client I get two files:
client.exe and
client.exe.config.
The second file contains configuration for the wcf client.

In my case I need to prevent the user sitting on the computer to see the urls and change some other parameters from the config file.

So the requirements are, the end user not to see and modify the data stored in the config. The config file contains the same data as app.config. I need to forbid the person using the program to see the end point urls so easy.

Also I have a lot of configuration there so I do not like to code in the moment.

Is there any solution for the problem (embedded app.config of something else)?

Edit: I do not need configurable options. The config file is automatically created when adding service reference from the studio.

Regards

Comment: You're kind of asking to have your cake and eat it too. You want it in the configuration because there is a lot of it, and you don't want it for sensitivity purposes. As far as I know, there really isn't a way to have both - embedding the configuration or hiding it, or otherwise.

Comment: I do not like to be configurable. When adding service reference the studio automatically creates the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create your proxies programatically instead of using the service reference feature.

Every parameter in the serviceModel config section can be represented in code as well.

The ChannelFactory class will help you create proxies to the service.

Comment: It seems this is the only solution. I tried to avoid it because I will need to write a lot of code instead of auto generated xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily encrypt entire parts of your config files - and not just web.config in web scenarios, but also application config's in stand-alone apps.

Check out some resources on how to do this:

- [Encrypting web.config values](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx)
- [Encrypting passwords in .NET app.config file](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx)
- [Encrypting the app.config file for Winforms application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/EncryptingTheAppConfig.aspx)